# Getting exception when dropdownbutton does not have value from Firebase document in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several dropdownbuttons in a flutter screen that I need to use for the user to select different service providers. right now, when I run the app, if there is not a value in the Firebase document for that particular dropdownbutton, I am getting an error and the screen displays red where the dropdown should be.

Below is a version of what I have to create the screen and this is only the dropdownbuttons.

How do I get the dropdownbuttons to display when nothing has been selected and there is nothing to initialize the dropdown that comes from the document?

I hope this makes sense.
Thanks in advance

```
String? _selectedInspectorCompany;
String? _selectedAppraiserCompany;
String? _selectedOtherCompany;
String? _selectedTitleCompany;
String? _selectedMortgageCompany;
String? _selectedOtherTitleCompany;

class TransactionDetailScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'transaction_detail_screen';
  final bool? newTrxn;
  final bool? isNewClient;

  const TransactionDetailScreen(this.newTrxn, this.isNewClient, {super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TransactionDetailScreen> createState() =>
      _TransactionDetailScreenState();
}

class _TransactionDetailScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<TransactionDetailScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
      final DocumentSnapshot _mlsId =
          await mlsRef.doc(ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).mlsId).get();
      _mlsSearchLink = _mlsId.get('mlsNbrSearch');
          _selectedInspectorCompany =
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['inspectorCompanyId'] ?? "Select Inspector Company";
          _selectedAppraiserCompany =
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['appraiserCompanyId'] ?? "Select Appraiser Company";
          _selectedTitleCompany = trxnSnapshot.data()?['titleCompanyId'] ?? "Select Title Company";
    }
Wrap(
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Inspector Company:    ',
    ),
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _db.collection('inspectorCompany').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> inspectorCompanyItems =
            [];
        inspectorCompanyItems.add(
            const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: 'a',
                child: Text('Select Inspector Company')));
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final inspectorCompanyList = snapshot.data!.docs;
          for (var inspectorCompany in inspectorCompanyList) {
            inspectorCompanyItems.add(
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: inspectorCompany.id,
                child: Text(
                  inspectorCompany['inspectorCompanyName'],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: const Text("Select Inspector"),
            value: _selectedInspectorCompany ??
                inspectorCompanyItems[0].value,
            onChanged: (inspectorCompanyValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedInspectorCompany =
                    inspectorCompanyValue;
              });
              ref
                  .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .updateInspectorCompanyId(
                      _selectedInspectorCompany!);
            },
            items: inspectorCompanyItems,
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ],
),

Wrap(
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Appraiser Company:    ',
    ),
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _db.collection('appraiserCompany').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> appraiserCompanyItems =
              [];
          appraiserCompanyItems.add(
              const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: 'a',
                  child: Text('Select Appraiser Company')));
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final appraiserCompanyList = snapshot.data.docs;
            for (var appraiserCompany in appraiserCompanyList) {
              appraiserCompanyItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: appraiserCompany.id,
                  child: Text(
                    appraiserCompany['appraiserCompanyName'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: const Text("Select Appraiser"),
            value: _selectedAppraiserCompany ??
                appraiserCompanyItems[0].value,
            onChanged: (appraiserCompanyValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedAppraiserCompany =
                    appraiserCompanyValue;
              });
              ref
                  .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .updateAppraiserCompanyId(
                      _selectedAppraiserCompany!);
            },
            items: appraiserCompanyItems,
          );
        }),
  ],
),

Wrap(
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Title Company:    ',
    ),
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _db.collection('titleCompany').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> titleCompanyItems = [];
          titleCompanyItems.add(const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: 'a', child: Text('Select Title Company')));
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final titleCompanyList = snapshot.data.docs;
            for (var titleCompany in titleCompanyList) {
              titleCompanyItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: titleCompany.id,
                  child: Text(
                    titleCompany['titleCompanyName'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: const Text("Select Title Company"),
            value: _selectedTitleCompany ??
                titleCompanyItems[0].value,
            onChanged: (titleCompanyValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedTitleCompany = titleCompanyValue;
              });
              ref
                  .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .updateTitleCompanyId(_selectedTitleCompany!);
            },
            items: titleCompanyItems,
          );
        }),
  ],
),

Wrap(
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Mortgage Company:    ',
    ),
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _db.collection('mortgageCompany').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> mortgageCompanyItems =
              [];
          mortgageCompanyItems.add(
              const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: 'a',
                  child: Text('Select Mortgage Company')));
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final mortgageCompanyList = snapshot.data.docs;
            for (var mortgageCompany in mortgageCompanyList) {
              mortgageCompanyItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: mortgageCompany.id,
                  child: Text(
                    mortgageCompany['mortgageCompanyName'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: const Text("Select Mortgage Company"),
            value: _selectedMortgageCompany ??
                mortgageCompanyItems[0].value,
            onChanged: (mortgageCompanyValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedMortgageCompany = mortgageCompanyValue;
              });
              ref
                  .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .updateMortgageCompanyId(
                      _selectedMortgageCompany!);
            },
            items: mortgageCompanyItems,
          );
        }),
  ],
),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this line:

```
value: _selectedInspectorCompany ?? inspectorCompanyItems[0].value
```

in this line, you are accessing the first element of the `inspectorCompanyItems` list, but the list is empty so it's throwing an error. write condition on building DropdownButton, Ex: `if(inspectorCompanyItems.isNotEmpty) return DropDownButton else return SizedBox();`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sometimes it works and sometimes I still get the red screen.